# PropertyChangeListener usage check

Tags: java

Good evening SO,

I wrote two pretty simple classes for one of my projects. This is the first time I met such a problem, so I would like to ask you if I managed to tackle the problem the right way / with good implementation.

The background is quite simple: You have a Channel that might be either busy or not. If the Channel is busy, it means it was taken by a ServiceRequest. Once the request is processed the Channel should be open again.

I googled a little bit and found ideas to use the PropertyChangedListener. Code down below. Please give me all the comments you can regarding the code quality / problem solving here. Thank you!

Test:

```
@Unroll
def "when request is processed and finished channel is free again"() {
    given:
    def channel = new Channel()
    def request = new ServiceRequest()
    request.addPropertyChangeListener(channel)
    when:
    channel.setRequest(request)
    request.finish();
    then:
    assert !channel.isBusy() && channel.request == null
}
```

Channel class:

```
public class Channel implements PropertyChangeListener{

private boolean busy;
private ServiceRequest request;

public Channel() {
    this.busy = false;
}

public boolean isBusy() {
    return busy;
}

public ServiceRequest getRequest() {
    return request;
}

public void setRequest(final ServiceRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
    busy = true;
}

@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    request = null;
    busy = false;
}
```

ServiceRequest class:

```
public class ServiceRequest {

PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

private String id;

public ServiceRequest() {
    id = "randomlygeneratedid";
}

void addPropertyChangeListener(final PropertyChangeListener l) {
    support.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
}

public void finish() {
    id = "";
    support.firePropertyChange("id", id, "");
    support.firePropertyChange("request", null, null);
    support.firePropertyChange("busy", null, false);
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: woops, sorry, my bad - youre probably right. Should I post the same question there or can it be moved?